# Wordpress how to apply css for specific roles using admin_head hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

I'm looking to add a line of code to apply `css` to certain roles.

For example:

If role "editor":

```
#wp-admin-bar-top-secondary{
    display:none;
}
```

My snippet code:

```php
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_style');

function my_custom_style(){
    echo '<style>
            
        /*remove media button*/
        .wp-media-buttons {
            display: none;
        }
        
        /*remove visual&code tabs*/
        .wp-editor-tabs {
            display: none;
        }
        
          </style>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `roles` property of the user object returned from [`wp_get_current_user`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) function.

```php
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_style');

function my_custom_style()
{
    $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

    if (!in_array('administrator', $roles)) 
    {
        ?>
        <style>
            /*remove media button*/
            .wp-media-buttons {
                display: none;
            }

            /*remove visual&code tabs*/
            .wp-editor-tabs {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    };
}
```

**Note:**

- Some users could possibly have more than one role, that's why I used `in_array` function!
- Of course you could do the opposite by using the exclamation mark/'not operator'. (i.e `!in_array()`)

Comment: thank you ~@Ruvee
after the post I thought of something simpler

it will be easier if the rules do not apply to administrators only

can you add this possibility?

Comment: Only for non `administrator(s)` you mean? Sure thing!

Comment: yes if no admin = apply all css

Comment: Got you! Updated my answer!